# Euler-Maclaurin summation for $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: summation, euler-maclaurin

I want to approximate the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k^2}$$
using the Euler-Maclaurin formula
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{2}(f(0) + f(\infty)) + \frac{1}{12}(f'(\infty) - f'(0)) - \frac{1}{720}(f'''(\infty) - f'''(0)) + \ldots$$

where $f(\infty)$ means $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$. But putting $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, it's not too hard to see that all derivatives of odd order are an odd polynomial times $f$, implying they vanish at $x = 0$. But this means *all* terms of the Euler-Maclaurin formula vanish except for the first two! But I *know* this is wrong because I evaluated the sum numerically in Mathematica.

What's wrong with my calculations?

Comment: Not totally sure, but could it be some kind of uniform convergence issue when you take the limit as $N \to \infty$, i.e., the $f^{(k)}(N)$ don't all tend to 0 at the same rate for larger and larger $k$?

Comment: Hmm... maybe. Is there a way to sidestep this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the details of the computation, but you are treating the Euler-Maclaurian formula as an equality, when it isn't.

Before continuing, I will switch the sum a little bit: You are working with
$$S:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-k^2}.$$
The formulas are a little cleaner in terms of 
$$T:=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2}.$$
These are related by $T=2S-1$, so it is easy to switch between them.

The [Euler-Macluarin formula with remainder term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_Maclaurin#The_remainder_term), combined with your correct computation that $f^{(k)}(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, tells us that we have
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2} = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{B_N(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)}{N!}  \frac{d^N e^{-x^2}}{(dx)^N}  dx$$
for any positive integer $N$. Here $B_N$ is the $N$-th Bernouli polynomial and $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $x$ rounded down to an integer. For some functions, the remainder $\int \frac{B_N(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)}{N!} \frac{d^N f}{(dx)^N} dx$ goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, but it often doesn't, and it doesn't in your case.

To give some other examples, if you compute the asymptotics of $\sum_{k \leq M} \frac{1}{k}$ using Euler-Maclaurin, the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) occurs as the limit of the remainder term. If you derive [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) by Euler-Maclaurin summation of $\sum \log k$, then the $\log (2 \pi)$ occurs as the limit of the remainder term.

There is a really good discussion of this in Chapter 9 of *Concrete Mathematics*, by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik. You might particularly enjoy the fourth example in Chapter 9.6, where they use Euler Maclaurin summation to show that, for any $N$, we have
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-k^2/t} = \sqrt{\pi t} + O(t^{-N}) \ \mbox{as}\ t \to \infty.$$

Comment: I see, so we have an upper bound on the error, but is there any way to, say, transform the sum so that we can get an Euler-Maclaurin series that actually converges to the correct value?

Answer (score 5):

Many examples of Euler-Maclaurin  summation are actually harmonic sums
and can be treated by Mellin transform methods.

In the present case put
$$S(x) = \sum_{k\ge 1} e^{-x^2 k^2}$$
with so that we are interested in $S(1/\sqrt{t})$
as $t\rightarrow\infty.$

This sum can be evaluated by inverting its Mellin transform.

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = e^{-x^2}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} x^{s-1} dx.$$
Use the substitution $x^2 = u$ so that $2x \; dx = du$ to get
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/2s-1/2} \frac{1/2 \; du}{\sqrt{u}}
= \frac{1}{2}
\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{1/2s-1} du = 
\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(s/2).$$

The  fundamental strip  of this Mellin transform is
$\langle 0,\infty\rangle.$

It  follows that  the Mellin  transform $Q(s)$  of the  harmonic sum
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(s/2) \zeta(s)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

The Mellin inversion integral for this transform is $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}  Q(s)/x^s ds$$  which we  evaluate by
shifting it  to the left for  an expansion about zero  (recall that as
$t\rightarrow\infty$ we have $1/\sqrt{t}\rightarrow 0.$)

Observe that the poles are at $s=1$ from the zeta function term and at
the non-positive  even integers from the gamma  function term. However
all of the  latter except the one at zero are  canceled by the trivial
zeros of the  zeta function term, leaving only the  poles at $s=0$ and
$s=1.$

For these two we have
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=1\right) = 
\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(1/2)\frac{1}{x} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2x}$$
and
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(Q(s)/x^s; s=0\right) =
\frac{1}{2} \times 2 \times  -\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}.$$

It follows that as $t\rightarrow\infty$ we have
$$S(1/\sqrt{t}) \sim \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi t} - \frac{1}{2}$$
and in particular
$$2S(1/\sqrt{t})+1 = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty e^{-k^2/t}
\sim \sqrt{\pi t}.$$

As for  the error  term if we  have shifted  the integral to  the line
$\Re(s) = -q/2$  with $q>1$ and $q$  odd we have for the  norm of the
zeta function term on the line $-q/2+iv$ the bound $|v|^{1/2+q/2}$ and the
gamma function  term decays  exponentially in $v$ along vertical lines 
and in $q$ at the values  at $-q/2$, so   the   error   term    decays exponentially   also.

Comment: It should say $q>1$ at the end, right? Or do you mean $\frac{-q}{2}$? Why does it have to be odd if the $\Gamma$ poles are gone? If you sum up all the integrals, you get the exact sum and not just better asymptotic descriptions, right?

Comment: I did mean −q/2. Thanks. I fixed it. If you sum all the integrals with their exact values you get the exact sum, but if you bound the left line integral, you get the initial terms of the expansion plus a bound.

Comment: As for where the expansion about 0 and integrals over $(-\frac{q}{2}-i\infty,-\frac{q}{2}+i\infty)$ come from, could I gather that from the rudiments of complex analysis or even just a complete understanding of the residue theorem?

Comment: You need to know how to determine the abscissa of absolute convergence of a Dirichlet series and the fundamental strip of a Mellin transform, which you compute by expanding the function being transformed in a series about zero and infinity to determine where both ends of the integral converge. The intersection of these two (half-plane of convergence and fundamental strip) gives the line for the Mellin inversion integral. Then use a rectangular contour and shift the left/right line integral to minus/plus infinity and compute the residues at the poles. There is more, consult any decent textbook

Comment: In the above and when working with harmonic sums the term half-plane of convergence refers to the Dirichlet series in the amplitudes/frequencies and the term fundamental strip refers to the convergence of the transform integral of the base function.