# Calculate integrals using Euler-Maclaurin's formula.

Tags: definite-integrals, euler-maclaurin

I am trying to calculate the following integral using Euler-Maclaurin formula. Found the end resault using an online intergrals calculator but I can't seem to get there on my own.

$$  \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} $$

I need an explanation on how to use the formula to calculate the integral and an explanation on what exactly is p in the formula.

Here is the Euler-Maclaurin's formula from wikipedia:

$$ \sum_{i=m}^n f(i) = 
    \sum_{k=0}^{2p}\frac{1}{k!}\left(B^\ast_k f^{(k - 1)}(n) - B_k f^{(k - 1)}(m)\right) + 
    R $$

Comment: Where is $p$ appearing ?

Comment: There are a few ways of writing Euler-Maclaurin slightly differently as far as I can see (haven't tried to see how they are equivalent yet), but this might help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719401/euler-maclaurin-summation-for-e-x2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
[image]

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x
> =\half\int_{0}^{2}\expo{-x^{2}/4}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&\approx\half\braces{\sum_{k = 1}^{1}\expo{-k^{2}/4} + \half\bracks{1 + \expo{-2^{2}/4}}
> - {1 \over 12}\bracks{-\,\half\,2\expo{-2^{2}/4}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,\expo{-1/4} + {1 \over 4} + {7 \over 24}\,\expo{-1}
> =\color{#c00000}{0.746}6985619
> \\[5mm]&\mbox{A more precise numerical integration yields}\quad 0.7468241328
> \end{align}

The exact result is $\ds{\half\,\root{\pi}{\rm Erf}\pars{1}}$.

> Information of the remainder can be seen in $\quad\large\tt\mbox{page 886}\quad$ of
>   [this table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_886.htm).

Comment: One thing I don't understand,  if you describe erf(1) in the resault and do the simplifications then you get exactly $  \int_0^1 e^{-x^2} $. So isn't this basically just like saying 2 = 2*2/2 ?